# Use XSLT to transpose some nodes in xml

Tags: xslt

I'm really struggling to figure out the xslt templates to apply for this one.  Here is my XML.

```
<root>
    <status>
        <isSuccess>true</isSuccess>
        <isSuccessSpecified>true</isSuccessSpecified>
    </status>
    <record>
        <itemId>52</itemId>
        <upcCode>C447009</upcCode>
        <displayName>501 CORE JEANS LEV 00501-0193 ORGNL FIT</displayName>
        <customFieldList>
            <value>false</value>
            <internalId>412</internalId>
            <scriptId>custitem_item_is_eligible</scriptId>
            <_typeName>BooleanCustomFieldRef</_typeName>
        </customFieldList>
        <customFieldList>
            <value>false</value>
            <internalId>213</internalId>
            <scriptId>custitem_nspos_is_pos_item</scriptId>
            <_typeName>BooleanCustomFieldRef</_typeName>
        </customFieldList>
        <internalId>130027</internalId>
        <_typeName>InventoryItem</_typeName>
    </record>
</root>
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve (extract /root/Record, with customfields transposed into standalone elements):

```
<record>
  <itemId>52</itemId>
  <upcCode>C447009</upcCode>
  <displayName>501 CORE JEANS LEV 00501-0193 ORGNL FIT</displayName>
  <custitem_item_is_eligible>false</custitem_item_is_eligible>
  <custitem_nspos_is_pos_item>false</custitem_nspos_is_pos_item>
  <internalId>130027</internalId>
  <_typeName>InventoryItem</_typeName>
</record>
```

I have already achieved what I think is the difficult part, and that is transposing the custom fields, but what I am struggling with is how to select all the OTHER, non-custom fields of the /root/record element.

Here is the XSLT I currently have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://exampleincludednamespace.com/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/record" /> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="root/record"/>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="root/record">
    <xsl:for-each select="//scriptId[contains(text(),'custitem')]"> 
      <xsl:element name="{.}">
        <xsl:value-of select="../value" />
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it generates the following output:

```
<custitem_item_is_eligible>false</custitem_item_is_eligible>
<custitem_nspos_is_pos_item>false</custitem_nspos_is_pos_item>
<record>
  <itemId>52</itemId>
  <upcCode>C447009</upcCode>
  <displayName>501 CORE JEANS LEV 00501-0193 ORGNL FIT</displayName>
  <customFieldList>
    <value>false</value>
    <internalId>412</internalId>
    <scriptId>custitem_item_is_eligible</scriptId>
    <_typeName>BooleanCustomFieldRef</_typeName>
  </customFieldList>
  <customFieldList>
    <value>false</value>
    <internalId>213</internalId>
    <scriptId>custitem_nspos_is_pos_item</scriptId>
    <_typeName>BooleanCustomFieldRef</_typeName>
  </customFieldList>
  <internalId>130027</internalId>
  <_typeName>InventoryItem</_typeName>
</record>
```

What changes do I need to make to the XSLT to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="itemId | upcCode | displayName"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="customFieldList">
                <xsl:element name="{scriptId}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="internalId | _typeName"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, this assumes that the value of `customFieldList/scriptId` will always be a valid XML element name.

Note that if the XML source contains more than one record, the result will be an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document. To prevent this, add a root element at the top level of the template. e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <records>
        <xsl:for-each select="record">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="itemId | upcCode | displayName"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="customFieldList">
                    <xsl:element name="{scriptId}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:copy-of select="internalId | _typeName"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </records>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/record"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='customFieldList']"/>
     <custitem_item_is_eligible>
        <xsl:value-of select="customFieldList[scriptId='custitem_item_is_eligible']/value"/>
      </custitem_item_is_eligible>
      <custitem_nspos_is_pos_item>
        <xsl:value-of select="customFieldList[scriptId='custitem_nspos_is_pos_item']/value"/>
      </custitem_nspos_is_pos_item>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaRC

Note : in XSLT 2.0+ you could use the 'except' keyword instead of name()!=